# Solved: How to create a working COPY INTO command for Snowflake ODBC?

Tags: c++, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, odbc

I am trying to use C++ to write SQL statements to pass through to the Snowflake ODBC driver. Currently, my staging command is working perfectly, however I cannot seem to get the COPY INTO command to operate correctly.

/// SOLVED: It is necessary to use closeCursor() before updating the statement being passed to the hstmt variable. You should not use SQLFreeHandle() until all messages have been passed.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE,
                         (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC, 0);

Statement = (SQLCHAR *)"PUT file:////home/fisheye/Documents/InfluxBenchmarks/competitor-benchmarks/SnowFlakeBenchmark1.0/fdata.csv @BENCHMARK.PUBLIC.%benchmark_test;";

retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, Statement, SQL_NTS);
// CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLPrepare(Statement)", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt);
if ((retcode != SQL_NEED_DATA) &&
    (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) &&
    (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    ;
// {CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLExecute()", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);}
if (hstmt != SQL_NULL_HSTMT)
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hstmt);
/// BROKEN HERE!!!
if ((retcode = SQL_SUCCESS) || (retcode = SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
{

    retcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(hstmt, SQL_ATTR_CURSOR_TYPE,
                             (SQLPOINTER)SQL_CURSOR_DYNAMIC, 0);

    // StatementCpy = (SQLCHAR *)"COPY INTO benchmark_test FROM @benchmark.public.%benchmark_test FILE_FORMAT = (type = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by = '\"') PATTERN = 'fdata.csv.gz';";
    StatementCpy = (SQLCHAR *)"COPY INTO benchmark_table FROM @~/staged FILE_FORMAT = (csv = csv field_optionally_enclosed_by = '\"') ;";

    retcode = SQLPrepare(hstmt, StatementCpy, SQL_NTS);
    // CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLPrepare(Statement)", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);

    retcode = SQLExecute(hstmt);

    // if ((retcode != SQL_NEED_DATA) &&
    //   (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS) &&
    //(retcode != SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO))
    //;
    // {CHECK_ERROR(retcode, "SQLExecute()", hstmt, SQL_HANDLE_STMT);}
}
else
    return 404.0;
```

Comment: Hi - what does “I cannot seem to get the COPY INTO command to operate correctly” mean? Does it error - in which case what error messages are you getting? Does it run but not achieve what you were expecting - in which case what does it do and what we’re you expecting? Please update your question with any additional information, rather than add it in comments